# "Mutex" Error when using Cryptopp with Windows Forms

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, mutex, crypto++

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 
An CLR application and I added a UI windows form 
I want include some Crypto++ functions into my Form header file so I add these lines after `#pragma once`

```
#include <string>
#include "base64.h"
#include "rsa.h"
#include "pem.h"
#include "osrng.h"
```

Windows forms needs to be compiled using /clr 
So my project setting enables Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) 
But that causes an error when building :

```
fatal error C1189: #error:  <mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.
```

It looks like Cryptopp is including  which is not compatible with /clr 
But if I disable /clr by changing it to `No Common Language Runtime Support` in the settings I get like hundreds of errors because Windows Form header code needs managed code means it needs /clr

So any solution so I can use Cryptopp in Windows Forms ?
Notice : I don't want use any other library for cryptography 
Thanks everyone !

**UPDATE :** 
An example of my program : 
Create a normal CLR Application then add an UI windows form, in the begging of form.h file add the lines found above then at any part of code (example in the form load section) add this :

```
string plain = "Test123", encoded, cipher;
string pkey = "...";
StringSource ss(pkey, true);
RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
PEM_Load(ss, publicKey);
RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(publicKey);

StringSource(plain, true,
    new PK_EncryptorFilter(prng, e,
        new StringSink(cipher)
    ) 
); 
StringSource((byte *)cipher.c_str(), cipher.size(), true,
    new Base64Encoder(
        new StringSink(encoded)
    )
);
```

Comment: The error is clear - you can't do that. One solution is to put the Crypto stuff in a (non CLR) dll. Another is not to use Winforms.

Comment: @MikeVine is it possible to create a (non CLR) dll and link it to a CLR project ?

Comment: Yes. Somerandomcharsascommentshaveaminlength.

Comment: @MeNotMe - `<mutex>` is brought in through [`<stdcpp.h>`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/stdcpp.h#L38) around line 40. We can probably guard it, but I suspect you will have trouble later from the `Singleton` class in [`misc.h`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/misc.h#L314) around line 300. If you open `config.h` and comment out the stuff around `CRYPTOPP_CXX11_SYNCHRONIZATION`, does that help the problem? If not, then I need a small program to duplicate the issue and the command line that produces the error.

Comment: @jww Thank you for you reply. In `config.h` everything around `CRYPTOPP_CXX11_SYNCHRONIZATION` is already commented out, for an example program, I'll update my question adding an example for it .. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @MeNotMe - A Crypto++ snippet is not enough. It does not have any WIndows Forms gear. I need a program with a `main`, and I need a command line to build it. I also need to know how you built the Crypto++ library and how you link it. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).